# Aligning div inside anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the `<div class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</div>` div to be aligned with the '@item.Title'. The div is currently getting centered vertically.

```js
//Accordion-----------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });
});

$(".accordion").click(function() {
  $(".accordion").not(this).find(".rotate").removeClass("down");
  $(this).find(".rotate").toggleClass("down");
});
//-----------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
  background-color: #2cc185;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #239768;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f4f3;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #74777b;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*Rotation-------------------------------------*/

.accordion .fa {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.rotate {
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.rotate.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*------------------------------------------*/

.link {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.accordion h4 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.accordion a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: #74777b;
  padding: 1em 1em 2.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2cc185;
  background-color: #e7ecea;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.accordion-desc {
  background-color: #f1f4f3;
  color: #74777b;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 20px 15px;
}

@media (min-width:480px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
}

.accordion-desc p {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.status {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 20%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <a href="#">
    <h4>@item.Title</h4>
    <div class="status">@Resource.AccordionStatus</div>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-desc">
  <h3>@Resource.AccordionProjectLead</h3>
  <h4>Kay Wiberg</h4>
  <h3>@Resource.AccordionDescription</h3>
  <p>
    @item.Description
    <p>
      <div class="link">
        <a href="@item.Url">@Resource.AccordionGoTo</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the following class.

```
.accordion h4 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}
```

Changes made:

Removed **top: 0.8em;** and just added **float:left**.

The issue is **h4** tag occupied full width and **div** tag is logically set in new line aligned with right side.

Comment: Thank you! works great! You think you get the concept of things. And then something small as this throws you of. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `display:inline-block` to align `@item.Title` to `@Resource.AccordionStatus` :

```
.accordion h4, .accordion .status {
    display:inline-block;
}

.accordion .status {
    top: 0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding float left to your H4

```
.accordion h4 {
    position: relative;
    /* top: 0.8em; */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
}
```

the problem is that h4 is displayed as a block element, then it push your floating right element to the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Correct with this :

```
   .accordion h4 {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 700;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```